# Getopt::Long and anonymous subroutine

Tags: perl

I've written the following code:

```
my $version = sub {
    print "$PROGNAME $VERSION - $AUTHOR\n";
    exit 0;
};

my $usage = sub {
    print "Usage: proll <options>\n";
    print "Available options:\n";
    print " -h, --help  Print this help and exit.\n";
    print " --version   Print version.\n";
    print " XdY     Launch X dice with Y faces.\n";
    exit 0;
};

my $ret = GetOptions ( "version" => \$version,
                       "h|help" => \$usage );
```

But also if I call the script with `--version` or `--help` it doesn't call the subroutine. Where am I wrong?

And if I change the code as follows, it always call the first subroutine also without any  command line parameter:

```
my $ret = GetOptions ( "version" => &$version,
                       "h|help" => &$usage );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\$version` is a reference to `$version`, where `$version` is a reference to an anonymous subroutine; so, `\$version` is a reference to a reference to a subroutine. That's too much indirection. You just need a single level of reference-ness:

```
my $ret = GetOptions ( "version" => $version,
                       "h|help" => $usage );
```

Comment: Alternatively, if it's a very short subroutine which is only going to get called based on options passed on the command line, you can simply use an anonymous subroutine: `GetOptions ( "dostuff" => sub { [do stuff here] } );`. This is useful for setting several variables at once, or instantiating an object in a special way.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Just to know: if it needs a reference, why it doesn't follow the reference "stream" until it find the end?

Comment: @Zagorax: `GetOptions` has a few different calling conventions (see [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html)). *One* way you can use it is the way that you're using it, where you pass in a reference to a subroutine to call if the option is present, but *another* way you can use it is to pass in a reference to a scalar that should be set to the value of the option if it's present. Since a reference is a type of scalar, `\$version` triggers the latter calling convention, so `GetOptions` thinks you want the value of `--version` stored in the variable `$version`.